# how to fire jquery load function after using change function

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list where i want to fire load function after user changes option in dropdown list , please help

```
var x = $("#catid");

x.change(function(){
    var y = $('#catid option:selected').val();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/";
    window.location= url+"master/posting/create/"+ y;


});
```

my main purpose here is to get rid off window.location and do that with load function to see select option in second menu. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the user to visit a url? You would use `$(elem).load(url)` to fetch data from that url and dump it into `elem`.

Comment: i want url to change when user select an option. Could you please advice me how to achieve that using change and load function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visit another url then there is no reason to change what you have. Using `window.location` is how you achieve that.

Comment: The prblem there is, when url location changes, the selected value is lost. I want to retain selected value on the page.

Comment: When the new page loads you should be able to match part of the URL (the part supplied by y) against values in the select and then set the appropriate option to selected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **$("#catid")** is the ID of the select box and let us assume a container **$("#result")** for the content of the load:

```
$("#catid").change(function(){
     var y = $(this).val();
     var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/";
     $("#result").load(url+"master/posting/create/"+ y);
});
```